# golang slice [:] matches with the last element

Tags: go

I am working on a sample program in golang which is as follows

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type thing [2]byte

func walk(things []thing, idx int) []byte {
    var match []byte
    for i, thing := range things {
        if i == idx {
            match = thing[:]
        }
    }
    return match
}


func main() {
    ta := []thing{ thing{'W','A'}, thing{'O','R'} }
    m := walk(ta, 0)

    tb := []thing{ thing{'C','A'}, thing{'W','Y'}, thing{'N','V'} }
    n := walk(tb, 1)

    fmt.Printf("m = %s\n", m)
    fmt.Printf("n = %s\n", n)
}
```

The output is:

```
m = OR
n = NV
```

I am not sure why this is the case when type thing [2]byte is an array of size 2 and ta is type []thing.

Now when you write the same code as this using [][]byte

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func walk(things [][]byte, idx int) []byte {
    var match []byte
    for i, thing := range things {
        if i == idx {
            match = thing[:]
        }
    }
    return match
}

func main() {
    ta := [][]byte{[]byte{'W', 'A'}, []byte{'O', 'R'}}
    m := walk(ta, 0)

    tb := [][]byte{[]byte{'C', 'A'}, []byte{'W', 'Y'}, []byte{'N', 'V'}}
    n := walk(tb, 1)

    fmt.Printf("m = %s\n", m)
    fmt.Printf("n = %s\n", n)
}
```

The output is

```
m = WA
n = WY
```

I am confused by these different behaviours of slices? 
Printing out `ta[:]` when `ta is type thing []byte` and `ta[:] when ta is [][]byte` is the same

Comment: It's not the same - `thing` is type `[2]byte`, not type `[]byte`. That is, it's an *array*, not a *slice*. The semantics are not the same.

Comment: @manugup1 allow me to point something over the code-design that may not right: if you know that you have `[2]byte` as elements of the slice, why, in your first example, are returing `[]byte`? If you return a `[2]byte` (an array) the algorithm works as expected. See for youself what i'm trying to say: https://play.golang.org/p/wOGaJ9Pwtck. Nevertheless this is a great example for understaning the slice internals....

Comment: BTW: this example goes straith to the matter: https://play.golang.org/p/GelDPKlNFO-

Comment: @manugulp1 yesterday i saw here a comment that give me thanks for providing more insight about the actual problem. You shouldn't erase comments like that, actually they help, by giving me positive feedback and encouraging me to keep contribuiting. Don't forget this place is, after all, a CoP (Community of Practices).

Comment: @Victor I have not removed any comment (at least not intentionally)! In fact, that comment was what helped me understand it the concept really well. I was surprised it was gone later.

Comment: Whoa... that's strange, i mean, nobody removes comments (and as a matter of code of conduct the remover shall explain to you why, in order to avoid next time to repeat the "error", if any...)... anyway, leaving that aside i would like to add that we all do great job in this post, we all share a lot of acknowledge, colaborate towards a common goal: to learn.

Comment: I leave you with a  *very special case* to study at home regarding slices affairs : https://play.golang.org/p/KwskY77tM-Y. Ja enjoy it!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases are ***not*** the same.

*In the first case*, you are working with `[][2]byte` (slice of arrays) not with `[][]byte` (slice of slices).

```
var match []byte
for i, thing := range things { // (2) change array on each iteration
    fmt.Printf("Thing %v", thing)
    if i == idx {
        match = thing[:] // (1) slice refers to array   
    }
}
return match // (3) here match slice refers to the last item of things
```

One of solutions here is adding `break` statement after `match = thing[:]`. It ends the loop and `match` will refer to expected array.

Just to clarify what is the actual issue here, the problem is that you are creating an slice that refers to an array that is overwritted in each *n-iteration* with the values of the correspondant *n-th element* of the slice of 2 bytes array. **So if you don't stop iterating the slice will get the values of the last element**.

Using a `for .. := range` "hides" a little bit this fact. I guess if you write the same code with a `for i;i<n;i++`, you could get a better understanding of what is actually happening: https://play.golang.org/p/z3hCskZ9ezV

Comment: i guess this would be an accepted answer, but may i inquire "how continuning iterating affect the returning result?" what is going on (that i don't see) in step (2)? Is there a kind of clousure here?? Guess no clousures here... sure is something related to the *sliceHeader* struct... really don't kwow and let me wondering...

Comment: It's a tricky behavior. ```match = thing[:]``` - here slice ```match``` collects refer to array. On each iteration ```thing``` variable has the same address - try ```fmt.Printf("Pointer %p \n", &thing)```. On the end of the loop ```thing``` is the last element, and thus ```match``` refers to its value.

Comment: well, thanks for the insight...i really don't see it coming... it has the same address, but different value... what is the meaning of that? .

Comment: For me it looks like that in each iteration the `thing`  (i mean, the [2]byte array used in each iteration) gets overwrited (by the correspondant values of n-th element)  thus modifyingt the underlying array to which the slice refers (as the `match = thing[:]`statement reflects) . So the problem is that we are slicing the **sole array** (i.e. short declared variable named "thing") used to **store the values in each iteration**?

Answer (score 2):

In one case, an individual `thing` is an array (`[2]byte`), and in the other, it's a slice (`[]byte`). In the first case, you're slicing an array into `match`, which gives you a new slice pointing at your loop iteration variable. In the second case, you're re-slicing an existing slice, so your new slice points at that slice's underlying array, even after the loop changes out the local slice variable.

Because your loop keeps running after you find your match, you find your match, slice it, then keep iterating, changing the value of the local loop iterator. If you did:

```
    if i == idx {
        return thing[:]
    }
```

instead, the issue disappears: https://play.golang.org/p/Uq4DbEGlGX8